# How to split string into array based on length in c#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am really stuck here and will appreciate the help. I have created a request data contract and a response data contract of a service. The request DTO contains Cardnum, Id and Noteline1----noteline18. The response DTO contains noteline1--noteline18.

I pass a string of character length 100 to the request data member noteLine1(data length of 78 characters). Now I want to make sure that only 78 character should be filled into the noteline1 data member and the rest should fit into the other empty noteline data member of request DTO. I used the following code and it worked fine for me:

```
string requestNoteReason = request.noteLine1;
if (response != null)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo reqPropertyInfo in requestPropertyInfo)
    {
        if (reqPropertyInfo.Name.Contains("noteLine"))
        {
            if (reqPropertyInfo.Name.ToLower() == ("noteline" + i))
            {
                if (requestNoteReason.Length < 78)
                {
                    reqPropertyInfo.SetValue(request, requestNoteReason, null);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    reqPropertyInfo.SetValue(request, requestNoteReason.Substring(0, 78), null);
                    requestNoteReason = requestNoteReason.Substring(78, requestNoteReason.Length - 78);
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    goto Finish;
}
```

Now I want that the noteline1 containing the string of more than 78 character length should split up and get filled in the next empty noteline. If the string is more than of 200 character length then it should split the string and fill it in the next consecutive empty noteline. For eg.if the string require the space of 3 empty noteline, then it should only fill the remaining characters string in the next consecutive available empty noteline.(i.e noteline2,noteline3,noteline4) and should not fill noteline with the string that was already filled before.

Please help

Comment: There's a arrow anti-pattern in code and there's goto statement, which shouldn't be used

Comment: the goto statement have other meaning. I have not written the whold code here. i have only written the code that needs to be implemented

Comment: I am just curious: why did you use properties noteline1..noteline18 instead of using an array of strings?

Answer (score 1):

```
[TestFixture]
public class Test
{
    [Test]
    public void TestLongLength()
    {
        var s = new string('0', 78) + new string('1', 78) + new string('2', 42);
        var testClass = new TestClass();
        FillNoteProperties(s, testClass);

        Assert.AreEqual(new string('0', 78), testClass.NoteLine1);
        Assert.AreEqual(new string('1', 78), testClass.NoteLine2);
        Assert.AreEqual(new string('2', 42), testClass.NoteLine3);
    }

    public static void FillNoteProperties(string note, TestClass testClass)
    {
        var properties = testClass.GetType().GetProperties();
        var noteProperties = (from noteProperty in properties
                              where noteProperty.Name.StartsWith("NoteLine", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                              orderby noteProperty.Name.Length, noteProperty.Name
                              select noteProperty).ToList();                
        var i = 0;
        while (note.Length > 78)
        {
            noteProperties[i].SetValue(testClass, note.Substring(0, 78), null);
            note = note.Substring(78);
            i++;
        }

        noteProperties[i].SetValue(testClass, note, null);
    }
}
```